# PostgreSQL using pg_trgm slower then full scan

Tags: postgresql

I playing with `pg_trgm` extension and I am confused a bit. Here is the session:

```
postgres=# create table t(i int, x text);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into t select i, random()::text from generate_series(1,50000000) as i;
INSERT 0 50000000
postgres=# explain analyze select * from t where x ilike '%666666%';
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=1000.00..531870.29 rows=12954 width=36) (actual time=131.436..11408.176 rows=432 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..529574.89 rows=5398 width=36) (actual time=108.771..11304.946 rows=144 loops=3)
         Filter: (x ~~* '%666666%'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 16666523
 Planning Time: 0.121 ms
 Execution Time: 11408.279 ms
(8 rows)

postgres=# explain analyze select * from t where x ilike '%666666%';
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=1000.00..580654.94 rows=5000 width=21) (actual time=124.986..11070.983 rows=432 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..579154.94 rows=2083 width=21) (actual time=72.207..11010.876 rows=144 loops=3)
         Filter: (x ~~* '%666666%'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 16666523
 Planning Time: 0.283 ms
 Execution Time: 11071.065 ms
(8 rows)

postgres=# create index i on t using gin (x gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX
postgres=# analyze t;
ANALYZE
postgres=# explain analyze select * from t where x ilike '%666666%';
                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=54.75..18107.93 rows=5000 width=21) (actual time=116.114..26995.773 rows=432 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (x ~~* '%666666%'::text)
   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 36257910
   Heap Blocks: exact=39064 lossy=230594
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on i  (cost=0.00..53.50 rows=5000 width=0) (actual time=75.363..75.363 rows=592216 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (x ~~* '%666666%'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.389 ms
 Execution Time: 26996.429 ms
(8 rows)

postgres=# explain analyze select * from t where x ilike '%666666%';
                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=54.75..18107.93 rows=5000 width=21) (actual time=128.859..29231.765 rows=432 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (x ~~* '%666666%'::text)
   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 36257910
   Heap Blocks: exact=39064 lossy=230594
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on i  (cost=0.00..53.50 rows=5000 width=0) (actual time=79.147..79.147 rows=592216 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (x ~~* '%666666%'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.252 ms
 Execution Time: 29231.945 ms
(8 rows)
```

As you can see that without index the query is more then two times faster then with index. Just for now there are default PostgreSQL settings (shared buffers, work memory etc)

What I missed?

PS: PostgreSQL 11.5 (Ubuntu 11.5-1.pgdg18.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit

PPS: Using `gist` index it is even slower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tldr: trigrams may not good at searching for patterns consisting of a single character repeated N times (such as `666666`) because there exists only 1 non-terminal trigram and that *could* have a high occurrence in the search space.

When the gin-index is used, the bitmap of rows is too large to fit in memory, so instead it stores reference to pages, and the database has to perform a further recheck scan over these pages. If the number of rechecked pages is small, the index-use is still beneficial, however with high number of recheck pages the index performs poorly. This is highlighted by the following lines in your explain output

```
   Recheck Cond: (x ~~* '%666666%'::text)
   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 36257910
   Heap Blocks: exact=39064 lossy=230594
```

The issue is particular to your search string, i.e. `666666`, with respect to the test data.

if you run `select pg_trgm('666666')`, you will find:

```
        show_trgm        
-------------------------
 {"  6"," 66","66 ",666}
(1 row)
```

The first 3 trigrams will not even be generated in an ilike context *(correction suggested by user [jjanes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1721239/jjanes))*. Searching on the index yields all pages containing `666`. You can validate this by running the explain analyze query with `... ilike '%666%'`, and obtaining the same `Heap Blocks` output as above.

if you search with the pattern `123456`, you will see it performs much better, because it generates a larger set of trigrams to search against:

```
              show_trgm              
-------------------------------------
 {"  1"," 12",123,234,345,456,"56 "}
(1 row)
```

On my machine, I get the following:

```
|------------------------------------|
| pattern | pages rechecked          |
|         | exact | lossy  | total   |
|------------------------------------|
| 123456  |   600 |        |    600  |
| 666666  | 39454 | 230592 | 270046* |
|    666  | 39454 | 230592 | 270046* |
|------------------------------------|
*this is rougly 85% of the total # of pages used for the table 't'
```

Here's the explain output:

```
postgres=> explain analyze select * from t where x ~ '123456';
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=90.75..18143.92 rows=5000 width=22) (actual time=110.962..113.509 rows=518 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (x ~ '123456'::text)
   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 83
   Heap Blocks: exact=600
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_x_idx  (cost=0.00..89.50 rows=5000 width=0) (actual time=110.868..110.868 rows=601 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (x ~ '123456'::text)
 Planning time: 0.703 ms
 Execution time: 113.564 ms
(8 rows)

postgres=> explain analyze select * from t where x ~ '666666';
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=54.75..18107.92 rows=5000 width=22) (actual time=137.143..18111.609 rows=462 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (x ~ '666666'::text)
   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 36258389
   Heap Blocks: exact=39454 lossy=230592
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_x_idx  (cost=0.00..53.50 rows=5000 width=0) (actual time=105.962..105.962 rows=593708 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (x ~ '666666'::text)
 Planning time: 0.420 ms
 Execution time: 18111.739 ms
(8 rows)

postgres=> explain analyze select * from t where x ~ '666';
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=54.75..18107.92 rows=5000 width=22) (actual time=102.813..17285.086 rows=593708 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (x ~ '666'::text)
   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 35665143
   Heap Blocks: exact=39454 lossy=230592
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_x_idx  (cost=0.00..53.50 rows=5000 width=0) (actual time=96.100..96.100 rows=593708 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (x ~ '666'::text)
 Planning time: 0.500 ms
 Execution time: 17300.440 ms
(8 rows)
```

Comment: "We know that no rows will match the first 3 trigrams, because spaces don't exist in your test data."  Even if he did have spaces in the test data, they wouldn't be searched for.  In an ILIKE context, the trigrams with spaces would not be generated.  (show_trgm is not aware of context, so it doesn't show this fact).

Comment: HaleemurAli Thanks for your answer, the problem becomes obviously after it. However you answered to the question "why?" but not to "how?" It seems that the PostgreSQL planner makes wrong decision about using index or not. Also to @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: @Abelisto That's hidden in the guts of `patternsel_common`, too hard for me to guess. But since the estimate is exactly 0.01%, it looks like some rule of thumb is at play. Does the estimate vary for different patterns?

Answer (score 2):

You already have a great answer which explains why '%666666%' is almost a worst-case scenario for pg_trgm with your sample data.

It is hard to say if this worst-case is a "fair" test or not.  Sometimes the worst case is both inevitable and performance-sensitive. If that is the case for you, then maybe this is a fair test.  On the other hand, worrying about the performance of demonic queries rather than actual ones is often a waste of time.

But there are some things you can do to improve the worst case performance.

> Heap Blocks: exact=39064 lossy=230594

The lossy blocks here are horrible for performance.  If you increase "work_mem" until those go away, it will probably close most of the gap between the index and the seq scan, or maybe even reverse it.  And it doesn't take very large settings, in my hands 20MB is enough.  That is a pretty conservative setting on a modern server.

If your table is larger than can be cached in RAM, then you will spend a lot of time reading data from disk.  If that is the case, increasing the setting of "effective_io_concurrency" might also help close the gap between the worst-case use of the index and the seq scan.

Another thing to know is that the seq scan is using 2 parallel workers.  So while it is finishing twice as fast, it might be using 3 times as much resources to do it.  (I don't understand why the index isn't using parallel bitmap scan--I would think it would be eligible)

If you can get the worst-case use of the index to be about the same as seq scan, and the average case to be far better, you have come out way ahead.