# Turn off recheck in trgm index

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, pg-trgm

We have a postgres column that uses the trigrams index (pg_trgm).

The index works well but is VERY slow: the final recheck for false positives consumes >99% of the overall query time (bitmap index scan 0.25s; recheck 30.7s).

In our case, false positives are irrelevant (rare + we don't care), so the recheck is useless.

Is there a way to turn off / disable the recheck step, to skip validating false positives? What's the best way to do it?

Comment: "the final recheck for false positives consumes >99% of the overall query time (bitmap index scan 0.25s; recheck 30.7s)."    How do you know this?  Recheck time is not reported separately from the other Bitmap Heap Scan time.

Comment: @jjanes plain `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, I saw nothing else taking place. What other possible culprits do you see?

Comment: Maybe, you have [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57685243/593144)?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you keep the indention of the plan.

Comment: "What other possible culprits do you see?"  It is hard to answer that based on your summary of the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS), rather than the actual output itself. But probably IO.

Comment: Yes, of course it's IO. I meant, what other major source of IO do trigrams have after a Bitmap Index Scan, apart from the Index Recheck? I didn't see any other candidates in the algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

I thought I already posted this, but apparently it never showed up.  Turning off the recheck is trivial if you are already set up to compile extensions:

```
diff --git a/contrib/pg_trgm/trgm_gin.c b/contrib/pg_trgm/trgm_gin.c
index 4dbf0ffb68..a23855cad5 100644
--- a/contrib/pg_trgm/trgm_gin.c
+++ b/contrib/pg_trgm/trgm_gin.c
@@ -307,7 +307,7 @@ gin_trgm_triconsistent(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
            /* FALL THRU */
        case LikeStrategyNumber:
            /* Check if all extracted trigrams are presented. */
-           res = GIN_MAYBE;
+           res = GIN_TRUE;
            for (i = 0; i < nkeys; i++)
            {
                if (check[i] == GIN_FALSE)
```

Of course this will give you wrong answers, which you seem to be OK with.  Your coworkers, present or future, may be astonished by this however, especially if they are using pg_trgm in some context removed from the present one.  So it should be documented clearly someplace.  You could fork pg_trgm into a new extension and make the change there, but it would require quite a bit of tedious renaming of functions and operators so they don't conflict.  Perhaps a better option would be to create a new version of pg_trgm which has an extra operator which implements this no-recheck feature, leaving ~~ (the thing LIKE is an alias for) to do what it currently does.  This would still present upgrade hazards, though.

Also, I doubt it will actually make things much faster.  Probably the time is actually being spent doing IO on the table, not doing rechecks.  You could check this by turning on `track_io_timing` and doing `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.  There are some cases where skipping the rechecks might also skip the IO, like if you are only counting the rows, not retrieving them.

Comment: Thanks! Isn't it also necessary to `*recheck = false;` inside `gin_trgm_consistent()`? When is that fnc used, versus `gin_trgm_triconsistent()`?

Comment: @user124114 I've verified that just my change is sufficient on recent versions (Pg >=9.6, pg_trgm >= 1.2).  I believe that gin_trgm_consistent is unused in any version new enough to have and use gin_trgm_triconsistent, and that it is retained only for backwards compatibility.  If you have upgraded Pg using pg_upgrade, then you should `alter extension pg_trgm update` to get that up to the newest version

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cannot disable recheck step but you can try to reduce the number of rechecks with increasing the parameter `work_mem` in the current session.

Comment: Any pointers to the relevant source code? There must be a way to disable it from there, even if it takes some tinkering + recompile.

Comment: @user124114: if you disable the re-check you'll get wrong results

Comment: I didn't search in the source code: I only checked if there was a query planner parameter. Of course if you change the source code it may be possible.

Comment: Yeah I'll try to sift through the code. Pointers welcome.
@a_horse_with_no_name that's irrelevant: please re-read the question.