# Postgres LIKE query triggers full table scan

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a Postgres query where we have several indices set up, including one on a text field where we have a GIN index. My understanding of this based on [the pg_trgm documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/pgtrgm.html) is that it's only applicable if the search string is made up of alphanumeric text. Testing bears this out and in a database with tens of millions of records, doing something like the following works great:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE target_field LIKE '%foo%'
```

I've read in various places that anything that's not an alphanumeric string is treated as a separate word in the trigram search, so something like the following also works quite well:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE target_field LIKE '%foo & bar%'
```

However someone ran a search that was literally just three question marks in a row and it triggered a full table scan. For some reason, when multiple ampersand or question marks are used alone in the query, they're being treated differently than a single one placed next to or among actual alpha-numeric characters.

The research I've done has implied that it might be how some database drivers handle the question mark, sometimes interpreting it as a parameter that needs to be supplied, but then gets confused because it can't find the parameters and triggers a table scan. I don't really believe this is the case. I might be inclined to believe it would throw an error rather than completing the query, but running it anyway seems like a design flaw.

What makes more sense is that a question mark isn't an alpha-numeric character and thus it's treated differently. In some technologies, common symbols such as & are considered alpha-numeric, but I don't think that's the case with Postgres. In fact, the documentation suggests that non-alphanumeric characters are treated as word boundaries in a GIN-based index.

What's weird is that I can search for `%foo & bar%`, which seems to work fine. I can even search for `%&%` and it returns quickly, though not with the results I wanted. But if I put (for example) three of them together like this: `%&&&%`, it triggers a full table scan.

After running various experiments, here's what I've seen:

1. `%%`: uses the index
2. `%&%`: uses the index
3. `%?%`: uses the index
4. `%foo & bar%`: uses the index
5. `%foo ? bar%`: uses the index
6. `%foo && bar%`: uses the index
7. `%foo ?? bar%`: uses the index
8. `%&&%`: triggers a full table scan
9. `%??%`: triggers a full table scan
10. `%foo&bar%`: uses the index, but returns no results

I think that all of those make sense until you get to #8 and #9. And if if the ampersand were a word boundary, shouldn't #10 return results?

Anyone have an explanation of why multiple consecutive punctuation characters would be treated differently than a single punctuation character?

Comment: May I ask what is the use of the '&'?

Comment: The ampersand character is just part of the text that's stored in the field and there are some entries in the database that contain either an ampersand or a question mark. I don't think any have both, but it's probably not relevant if they did.

Comment: That's not true. You would be correct if it were a btree index, but it's a Trigram index. I stated that at the beginning. Read this on Trigram Indexes: https://scoutapm.com/blog/how-to-make-text-searches-in-postgresql-faster-with-trigram-similarity

Comment: It's PostgreSQL 11.8. I could likely upgrade if need be, but there's logistical challenges, so it's not an overnight thing. I was considering simply stripping out any non-alphanumeric characters from the query, replacing them with spaces, removing double spaces and then putting it back together into a string to run the query. But I would prefer to understand the underlying problem before doing that kind of thing.

Comment: Not sure that it is your case but here is great explanation about trigram indexes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57685243/593144

Comment: You know, I'd read that question but I missed the part about trigrams not being good for searching patterns of repeating characters. That said, I ran both SELECT show_trgm('%&%'); and SELECT show_trgm('%&&&%'); but they came back with exactly the same result, which was an empty dictionary. I also have a btree index on the same column, so perhaps it's hitting that index for single character searches. I don't think there's a way to know for sure except to drop that index and try it.

Comment: BTW If you need the search only for particular character then condition index could to help: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6fa8bdc4a244d9d2433219af84861fee

Comment: It's not about searching for a particular character, so much as it is identifying what kinds of characters cause it to run a full table scan and intercepting those before the execute on the database because we know in advance they're going to be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce this in v11 on a table full of md5 hashes: I get seq scans (full table scans) for the first 3 of your patterns.

If I force them to use the index by setting enable_seqscan=false, then I go get it to use the index, but it is actually slower than doing the seq scan.  So it made the right call there.  How about for you?  You shouldn't force it to use the index just on principle when it is actually slower.

It would be interesting to see the estimated number of rows it thinks it will return for all of those examples.

> In fact, the documentation suggests that non-alphanumeric characters are treated as word boundaries in a GIN-based index.

The G in GIN is for "generalized".  You can't make blanket statements like that about something which is generalized.  They don't even need to operate on text at all.  But in your case, you are using the LIKE operator, and the LIKE operator doesn't care about word boundaries.  Any GIN index which claims to support the LIKE operator must return the correct results for the LIKE operator.  If it can't do that, then it is a bug for it to claim to support it.

It is true that pg_trgm treats & and ? the same as white space when extracting trigrams, but it is obliged to insulate LIKE from the effects if this decision.  It does this by two methods.  One is that it returns "MAYBE" results, meaning all the tuples it reports must be rechecked to see if they actually satisfy the LIKE.  So '%foo&bar%' and '%foo & bar%' will return the same set of tuples to the heap scan, but the heap scan will recheck them and so finally return a different set to the user, depending on which ones survive the recheck.  The second thing is, if the pg_trgm can't extract any trigrams at all out of the query string, then it must return the entire table to then be rechecked.  This is what would happen with '%%', '%?%', '%??%', etc.  Of course rechecking all rows is slower than just doing the seq scan in the first place.

Comment: If the query uses the index, it's typically under 2 seconds, but a full table scan takes a little over 2 minutes and it pegs the disk IO for the database the entire time, causing other queries to bog down. This is the back-end of a mobile app, so the speed of the query is important and using an index is preferable. I'm wondering if the solution is to check in advance if any trigrams exist and if not, return nothing rather than do the table scan. Seems like a small price to pay to intercept those DB-killing queries. Thoughts?

Comment: Does "typically" mean for `%&%`, or is that averaged over a bunch of other less pathological things which bring down the average?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "typically" as in when the index is able to be used shown in examples 1-7 & 10 from my original question. I've been tracking down performance issues like this and noticed that some random user searched for ???, which forced the table scan. I'm trying to figure out what the underlying cause was and then decide on how to deal with it. For that, it appears there aren't any valid trigrams. But it doesn't make sense to me that both %?% and %???% have no valid trigrams, but the first returns immediately and the second does not. Maybe it's using a different index.

Comment: It is hard to believe that 1-3 are fast.  4-7 and 10, sure they could be fast.  Can you show the full `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for one of them?  I agree that `%?%` and `%???%` both have no valid trigrams, and I can't reproduce them leading to different plan structures.  Could you show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for both of those?

Comment: Any chance you are running a custom compilation of pg_trgm in which someone undefined KEEPONLYALNUM before compiling?

Comment: I think that I figured it out. When I gave the example, I simplified it quite a bit and neglected the fact that there's a LIMIT 10 at the end of the query(which I thought I'd tested). If I query for COUNT(*) using %&% as the WHERE clause and leave out LIMIT 10, it does a full table scan. As I mentioned, I do have another btree index on that field. I think what's happening is that the btree index is being used and when as it crosses 820506 records, filtered 6448 rows, it knows it hit the limit and returns. But %&&&% doesn't match either index, so it does a full table scan.